# Hidden Metadata in DJI drone .JPG

Tags: image-processing, import, image, metadata

I have imported a JPG file with MetaInformation (Exif/XMP) however all the available tags are not imported. The JPG is a DJI drone image with meta information as: altitude, YAW, GeoPosition, etc.
Some the information is omitted when imported into mathematica. If I run the same JPG through a Exif viewer, the additional parameters are presented.

Anyone recommend a fix/workaround SVP

Comment: If I recall correctly,  DJI images often have some of their metadata in a specialized XMP location (`XMP-drone-dji` group) rather than standardized locations such as EXIF, `XMP-exif`, or `XMP-iptcExt `.

Answer (score 2):

The metadata is visible with a newer version of Mathematica 12.3

Comment: What version you used previously (that didn't import metadata)?

Comment: version 12.1 didn't import everything